# No warning/error for exported function is missing implementation when building dll

Tags: c++, dll

I noticed that when creating a dll in Visual Studio, a function declared **__declspec(dllexport)**, but with **no implementation**, is silently **dropped** from the **dll**. So no error is encountered until that particular function is called by a client, and an unsatisfied link error is generated.

I encountered this today when a colleague renamed a function, but only committed the change in the header, and not the source file, and the function was silently dropped from our dll exports from then on.

I tried warning level 4 in VS2013, and not even a warning appeared.

I am wondering now if there are other misnamed pairs in our library. Certainly it would be great if the compiler at least warned about this, but ideally this would cause an error.

Question, does anyone know how to cause a warning/error for missing implementation for a dllexport  in Visual Studio?

We build our library on all the popular OS and compilers, and all build fine with no errors (though perhaps a warning we've never noticed...)

Comment: That is not possible.  Having such declarations in a .h file but not in one of the source files is entirely normal.  Only the linker could generate such an error, it doesn't know what is in an .h file.

Comment: You are saying it is 'normal' to declare a function as dllexport, but never implemented in a DLL?
When would this be? When the implementation is in another DLL?
Anyway, my real issue is that the linker knew enough to drop the exported function from the dll, yet it doesn't bother to warn at all?

Comment: The only way to avoid this I think is to build a test case that attempts to call all the functions that should be exported from the DLL.